# Is there any way to aggregate data before sending it back to the user?

Tags: database, algorithm

I came across with the problem where I need to query data from external data provider, but instead of getting back original data, I need to get back aggregated data.

For example:

```
"select * from person p where p.age < 40 and p.income > 30000"
```

and service provider would return:

```
ages 20...30          | ages 30...40
there are 454 persons | there are 23 persons
```

instead of 477 (454 + 23) different rows.

I came across with Shamir’s secret sharing and Rabin's Information Dispersal Algorithm but not sure if these things are the way to go.

It doesn't need to be on database level. It can be some sort of algorithm that aggregates data before sending it back to the user.

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Google `sql group by clause`.

Comment: I know what group by clause is. That is not the point.

Comment: You can get the logical grouping that you outline above with a `group by`, so is it the concrete formatting of the result that you are having difficulty with?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot magically have it know how to group data.  But you can ask for a grouping like this:

```
SELECT
    CASE -- I will include more buckets because it is easy.
        WHEN p.age < 10 THEN '0..10'
        WHEN p.age < 20 THEN '10..20'
        WHEN p.age < 30 THEN '20..30'
        WHEN p.age < 40 THEN '30..40'
        WHEN p.age < 50 THEN '40..50'
        WHEN p.age < 60 THEN '50..60'
        WHEN p.age < 70 THEN '60..70'
        WHEN p.age < 80 THEN '70..80'
        WHEN p.age < 90 THEN '80..90'
        ELSE '90+'
    END AS age_bucket
  , COUNT(*) AS people
FROM person p
WHERE p.age < 40 and p.income > 30000
GROUP BY 1;
```

You can move the groups to its own table and make the bucketing a join instead of a case statement.  You can have several category buckets that you join to slice and dice data multiple ways.

The tool works well.  But you have to tell it exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for this! Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but I am looking for a idea (if there is) where sending any query (e.g simple select * from table) and getting back dispersed or scattered or aggregated data.

Comment: @AverageJoe9000 What you seem to be asking for is to be able to make a straightforward query and have it figure out the something else that you'd prefer instead.  No, that doesn't exist.  And attempts to build that tend to break pretty badly when it thinks you mean something different than you did.

Comment: You have to learn how to tell it to do exactly what you actually want it to do.

Comment: Yes, I tried to explain it as simple as I could but it came out something totally easy. Anyways, ill try to fix myself. Thanks!